# string constant storage

Tags: c

Is there any difference between the two functions below isn't in both cases the address of local variable returned, but the using the f1() fn returns the correct value 4 but not f2(). Also in third case am I right about this that string constant are not stored in stack so when we return the pointer it will work fine. Also then where are string constant are stored?

```
int* f1()
{
  int* a=(int*)4;
  return a;
}

int* f2()
{
  int a=4;
  return &a;
}

char* f3()
{
  char* p="abcd";
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the two functions -- and you had given 3 functions! :)

Comment: For the record, you shouldn't be returning pointers to stack variables like that. That memory will quite likely be used for something else after the function exits.

Comment: Shouldn't someone have made a snide comment "is this homework" by now lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are differences between all of them:

1. The first returns an `int *` with the value 4, note that it doesn't point to a variable with the value 4, but to the address 4.
2. The second returns a pointer to a variable that holds 4, but actually, this pointer is not valid, as it points to a local variable of an already returned function, and any usage of it will result in undefined behavior.
3. The third returns a pointer to char (by definition), but actually this is a pointer to a string literal (by implementation). The problem with it, is that as the function return `char *` and not `const char *`, one may try to modify the return buffer, which will, again result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I know I didn't even bother to start typing the answer

Comment: In f3() where is the string literal actually stored(not in stack right?) as we are able to access even after the function returns. Also why is string literal const char* is it just language construct or something else???

Comment: The string literal is stored in "read only" data section (not the stack) and the const is since it's in the read only data section.

Comment: @grv: If you had instead made f3()'s string as follows:  char p[]="abcd";    ...the compiler would automatically copy the string literal's const contents into a stack buffer of the same size (5 bytes, 1 for each letter & another for the terminating nul).  But if you defined it as    const char p[]="abcd";   ...then you'd be back where you were before (sort of)... the buffer wouldn't be copied, and your 'p' array would not be stack-allocated, and no copy would be made (the compiler would just use the string literal's storage for p[]), with one difference that's sometimes important: ...

Comment: ...Since p is a const array and not a char pointer, you can take its size (sizeof(p) ) and get size 5 from it without having to use strlen() or manually counting characters.  Note that if you try to use sizeof(p) on your original code, you'd get probably 4 or 8, depending on whether your app is compiled for a 32-bit or 64-bit platform.  The 4 or 8 in that case has nothing to do with the length of the string, it's just the size of a pointer on your system.

Answer (score 1):

- `f1` casts the value 4 to an address, in effect pointing somewhere in memory.
- `f2` Returns the address of a local variable. Dereferencing this pointer will be undefined behavior.
- `f3` is a pointer to a string literal. This is a valid pointer as the lifetime of a string literal is the same as the program lifetime (*static storage duration*). Where exactly this literal is stored is defined by the implementation. Manipulating the contents of a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't f1 pointing to address 0x4 (rather than "somewhere in memory")?

Comment: @ScottWilson Correct. Given virtual memory I consider that to be "somewhere" :) Every pointer that you don't obtain in a safe way or by hardcore knowledge of the underlying machine is so useless that its value doesn't matter much.

Comment: So is it that all the string literal have static storage?? Also why is the string literal defined as const char* is it just language construct or there is some reason??

Comment: @grv - see the comment to the exact question under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- In `f1` you have explicitly specified address `4` and returned the same and not the value at that address.
- Local variables are allocated on stack and so in `f2` where you returned `&a`, you are returning an address on stack and not the `4` which is present at that address in memory. De-referencing this address leads to undefined behavior as the function is flushed off the stack.
- String literals are allocated on read-only data section and note the difference between

  `char arr[]="abcd";` and `char *ptr="abcd";`

  the first is a character array and is allocated on stack while the second is a pointer to a string literal which (literal not pointer) is allocated on read-only data section.

PS: I have assumed GCC/x86 here.

Comment: There is no `could` in `f2`. Dereferencing that pointer is UB, no matter what has been flushed or not.